# Does Crosswalk support HSTS and HPKP?

Tags: crosswalk-runtime, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

Does Crosswalk support HSTS and HPKP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, HSTS and HPKP are supported by Crosswalk. [See Crosswalk unit tests...](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/chromium-crosswalk/tree/master/net/data/url_request_unittest)